# Midnight Commander on OSX - bindings for file extensions and arrows

Tags: macos, file-extension, midnight-commander, bindings

I am using Midnight Commander on Mac OS X (version 4.8.4)

I have two problems and I would be very glad if you can help me:

**First:**

The binding for file extensions are set for Linux distribution.  For example, if I try to open some jpg file:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/midnight-commander/4.8.4/libexec/mc/ext.d/image.sh: line 39: gqview: command not found
```

Has anyone gotten this binding file to work on Mac OSX? (open pdf file in Preview, etc)

**Second:**

I am used to so called "lynx-like movement" - to be able to enter a directory with only an arrow key (and to leave a directory with an arrow key).  But this option is not in my MC (it is working on Ubunut's MC for ages...)

Answer (score 10):

Start `mc`, click on `Command` and then on `edit extension file` (or `F9, c, e`). Then, for example, search (`F7`) for `pdf` and change

```
<------->Open=(xpdf %f &)
```

into

```
<------->Open=(open %f &)
```

How exit and save (`F10`). Changes are immediately applied.

`open` Starts Preview by default. Repeat this for all extensions you want te re-bind. As long as you agree with LaunchServices, you can use `open`. You can also just use any specific application.

Other usefull additions to `mc.ext`:

```
# PowerPoint
regex/\.([pP][pP][tT]?[xX])$
        Open=(open %f &)

# Word
regex/\.([dD][oO][cC]?[xX])$
        Open=(open %f &)

# Excel
regex/\.([xX][lL][sS]?[xX])$
        Open=(open %f &)
```